# Could "idem" used as an answer to a question?

Tags: expressions

I went to a French restaurant with my friend. I requested a dish, then the server asked my friend in French and my friend replied "***idem***".

Is it correct to use "*idem*" as an answer in this context? What about *"pareil"*?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Technically, yes, “*idem*” means “the same”, “likewise”. But in practice I would not use it, and a waiter might not recognize the word, especially in a noisy environment. It's completely non-idiomatic in this context. To say that I want the same thing as the previous person, I would say “*la même chose*” or “*pareil*”.

In a restaurant context specifically, there's a fairly idiomatic way of phrasing that you want the same thing as the previous person: “***un deuxième***” or “***une deuxième***” (depending on whether the word for the dish is masculine of feminine). If the next person again wants the same thing, they'd say “*un(e) troisième*” or just “*troisième*”, etc.

Answer (score 2):

according to https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/idem

> Adverbe
>
> idem \i.dɛm\ invariable
>
> ```
> De même, pareillement. On l’emploie pour éviter de répéter ce qui vient d’être dit ou écrit.
>     Voici la lettre. Tu sais ce que tu as à faire. Un fiacre est en bas. Pars tout de suite, et reviens idem. — (Victor Hugo, Les
> ```
>
> Misérables, Tome III, 1890, p. 421)

Idem can be use as "pareil" and "la même chose" when ordering at restaurant.

Selon https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Mis%C3%A9rables

> Nombre de pages   2 598 (éd. Testard, **1890**)

Comment: Les Misérables est paru en 1862.

Answer (score 0):

**Idem** is straight from Latin, and means **the same** in Latin. In English, we use **ditto** (also Latin) in exactly the same way.

Comment: The question is not about *idem* meaning but about whether it is idiomatic or not in the OP context. The answer is no. It is not something usual as a reply to a waiter.

Comment: God forbid we add any additional snippets of perhaps interesting information that doesn't answer the question strictly.

Comment: I have no idea about God opinion about it, but SO rules make a clear distinction between comments and answers.

Answer (score 0):

Selon [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/idem/41407#difficulte)

> Idem, employé pour aussi, de même, est familier : il est reçu à l'examen, et moi idem.